# How do native speakers of English say "To inherit a behavior"?

Tags: meaning, idiom-requests, translation, phrase-requests

I was trying to translate  a text from Brazilian-Portuguese into english and I got stuck at a slang phrase we have. Here in Brazil, we use the word "puxar" (*"to pull"* in English) with an additional meaning close to: *"to inherit or mimic a parent's trait or behavior"*. I'm not sure if there is an equivalent word or phrase in English.  Can anyone help me find a verb or a verb-like expression that means it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some colloquial English phrases for 'a child acquiring its parents' characteristics or features'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97741/what-are-some-colloquial-english-phrases-for-a-child-acquiring-its-parents-cha) and [Questions on 'like father like son'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310290/questions-on-like-father-like-son/310302#310302).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"take after"** is the phrase you're looking for.

The young boy surely takes after his dad, see how he enjoys soccer.

> - [**take after**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+after) - "to be like or to look like someone in your family."
>
> If you take after a member of your family, you resemble them in your appearance, your behaviour, or your character. -  [**Collins**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-after)

- Most of my children **take after** my husband, both in appearance and character.
- She **takes after** her grandfather in her talent for design.
- You **take after** your mother—you have her nose and eyes.

Comment: You really ought to look for likely duplicates before repeating answers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I expect that's what you say to every member here who answers a duplicate, irrespective of who they are.

Comment: No; the probability increases dramatically with the likely non-checker's (and an in-house search for 'take after' leads rapidly to the original) reputation.

Answer (score 0):

We have an idiom "the apple doesn't fall far from the tree" to convey this though it is not very succinct. Perhaps "family mimicry"?

Comment: I was asking for something that could be used like a verb, anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Where I'm from, we say that someone "got it honest."

Another way to say it is to say that you came by something honestly.

"Fig. to inherit something—such as a character trait-from one's parents. 'I know I'm mean. I came by it honestly, though.' 'She came by her kindness honestly.'"